# Prevent Macros from running on source workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a source workbook which I am storing all my macro codes in.
I use ***most*** of the macros on other open workbooks sheets (by keeping the sourcebook open).

My question:
How do I prevent certain macro codes (not all) from being executed on the source file sheets by mistake (as I am letting other users use these macros, but I don't want them to mess with original file sheets by running certain macros), but run on any other open workbook?

thanks

Comment: One approach would be to change the macro so the first thing it does is prompt the user to select the target workbook and check the workbook name to make sure it is not the current workbook.

Comment: The easier solution to me was to give users less options thus prompting the user would make more hastle I guess. I put a code to check the file name then inform the users that they are using the wrong active workbook. Then code exits.

Answer (score 0):

Found A solution

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Name = "Name.xlsm" Then
  MsgBox ("Custom Message to show to User")
Exit Sub
Else
End If
```

Comment: O yes of course! That should work in most (if not all) cases. Or even If ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then ...

Comment: :) :) I am glad now

Answer (score 0):

### Test Workbook

- You could copy the function to a standard module of your `Source Workbook` and run something like the one-liner from the `example Sub` in critical places of your codes. You don't want to 'pollute' your other codes with more than one line.

```vb
Function testThis() As Boolean
    If ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then
        MsgBox "You cannot do this to 'My Precious'!"
        testThis = True
    End If
End Function

Sub InCriticalPlaces()
    If testThis Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```